# pandas how to split twice a given field

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I would like to count the top subject in a Column. Some fields have commas or dot I would like to create a new row with them.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

sbj = DataFrame(["Africa, Business", "Oceania", 
    "Business.Biology.Pharmacology.Therapeutics", 
    "French Litterature, Philosophy, Arts", "Biology,Business", ""
     ])
sbj
```

[image]

I would like to split into a new any field that has a '.' or '.'

```
sbj_top = sbj[0].apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x.split(",")) if not pd.isnull(x) else pd.value_counts('---'.split(","))).sum(axis = 0)
sbj_top
```

I'm getting an error (`AttributeError`) here while try to re-split('.') it

```
sbj_top = sbj_top.apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x.split(".")) if not pd.isnull(x) else pd.value_counts('---'.split(","))).sum(axis = 0)
sbj_top
```

My desired output

[image]

```
sbj_top.sort(ascending=False)
plt.title("Distribution of the top 10 subjects")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
sbj_top.head(10).plot(kind='bar', color="#348ABD")
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: A quick look at of the output from the first split shows spaces in the results.  You need to use trim().

Comment: Do you want to preserve the original index? E.g., should the first line turn into "0, Africa" and "0, Business"?

Comment: Hi @cphlewis I just want to do `value_counts()` so that I can make a `.plot()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Counter together with chain from itertools.  Note that I first replace periods with commas before parsing.

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools
from string import whitespace

trimmed_list = [i.replace('.', ',').split(',') for i in sbj[0].tolist() if i != ""]
item_list = [item.strip(whitespace) for item in itertools.chain(*trimmed_list)]
item_count = Counter(item_list)

>>> item_count.most_common()
[('Business', 3),
 ('Biology', 2),
 ('Oceania', 1),
 ('Pharmacology', 1),
 ('Philosophy', 1),
 ('Africa', 1),
 ('French Litterature', 1),
 ('Therapeutics', 1),
 ('Arts', 1)]
```

if you need the output in the form of a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(item_list, columns=['subject'])
>>> df
           subject
0               Africa
1             Business
2              Oceania
3             Business
4              Biology
5         Pharmacology
6         Therapeutics
7   French Litterature
8           Philosophy
9                 Arts
10             Biology
11            Business
```